# How to delete RAV Antivirus on my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, virus-removal

How can I delete RAVAntivirus from my computer.

There is no way I can delete this outrageous app from my computer. There will be an error in the control panel, as well as uninstall.exe, the folder cannot be deleted from Windows Explorer because it is in use by another application and Task Manager will be blocked if I try to close the process.

If I download anything from the web or make I own applications, I will immediately get a message: "This file contains a virus!" and it disappears! Please help!!!

Comment: Windows Defender stopped working and it just reads: Windows Defender disabled because service provider is switched.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbqaFPrfJkg

Answer (score 2):

A regular antivirus ought be be able to remove it - get one you've heard of at least - see https://file-intelligence.comodo.com/windows-process-virus-malware/exe/rav who have a freeware remover.

If you can't get anything to install on the computer, you might have to pull out the drive & do this from another machine.

…and in future read all dialogs when you're installing things. RAV gets onto computers because the user actually allowed it. It's not technically malware itself, it's just a useless PoS designed to make you think everything's infected, so you'll buy it. It's sometimes masked in malware too. You may have got the latter.

Else see [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: I installed a program that asked if you allowed RAVAntivirus to be installed, and I accidentally pressed yes. It also asked about installing Opera.

Comment: I'm not sure which is worse!

Comment: Tetsujin ,your answer is very useful but not fix my problem. But I fixed it with [Unlocker](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) software.

Answer (score -3):

I got a similar issue recently and reached out to [their support on their website](https://reasonlabs.com/contact-us).
They showed me how to uninstall the app, basically by fixing the original install and then using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06jIQf9Gvws) for removing the program from my computer.
After this I was able to successfully resolve the problem and unisntall this as a regular program.